# Direct inclusion of resulting link file during export in Org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I'm preparing static html site with interactive Javascript components visualizing my research data in Org mode. Javascript components are returned by the Org Babel Python script in form of HTML string representation.

Suppose I'm editing an org file intended for HTML export inside of which I have a python script that returns HTML string representation of a chart (for instance objects created by libraries such as [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io), [Plotly](https://plotly.com), etc.), and a source block with following arguments

```
#+begin_src python :exports results :results file :file chart.html
<<block returning an HTML string representation of a chart>>
#+end_src

#+results:
[[file:chart.html]]
```

As described in [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Links-in-HTML-export.html#Links-in-HTML-export) the HTML export back-end transforms links to equivalent HTML links in the output, which is not what I want.

I would like to include the content of an HTML file directly in the output HTML file. Actually Org is already using similar approach in case of image files like `.png`, `.jpg` etc. The LaTeX export back-end [processes](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-LaTeX-export.html#Images-in-LaTeX-export) image links in Org files as direct image insertions. In the final PDF output they are no longer links but actual images embedded on the page. Images in HTML export [behave in the same manner](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-HTML-export.html#Images-in-HTML-export).

The default option is to use a source block in the form

```
#+begin_src python :exports results :results html
<<block returning an HTML string representation of a chart>>
#+end_src
```

but in my case it can't be used since the script generates a huge content with extremely long lines, as a result Emacs freezes and needs to be restarted. As a matter of fact, this [well known](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Long-Lines.html) Emacs issue is **the main reason** why I'm looking for a different scenario.

Second alternative stem from the fact that code blocks can be evaluated during export (without the need of creating the long line content). This solution works (provided that the code block is not evaluated in Org buffer), but has one drawback: results of evaluation can't be cached.

Third possibility is to use

```
#+include: "chart.html" export html
```

after the code block

```
#+begin_src python :exports none :results file :file chart.html
<<block returning an HTML string representation of a chart>>
#+end_src
```

but this time I must run code block manually and place the `#+include` line after execution, which scales badly when the number of blocks rises (automatic solution would be much better).

Perfect solution would be to have an additional new `format` option (see [docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html#Results-of-Evaluation)) for the `results` (let's call it `include`) that would allow for direct inclusion of resulting files, given their links:

```
#+begin_src python :exports results :results file include :file chart.html
<<block returning an HTML string representation of a chart>>
#+end_src

#+results:
[[file:chart.html]]
```

Does it come to anyone's mind how to achieve direct inclusion of resulting link file during export in Org mode, in a way similar to the aforementioned `:results file include` solution?

### Conclusions after the battle

---

- I've focused too much on the inclusion mechanism, but main issue here concerns long lines resulting from JSONs objects occurring in HTML strings. By modifying python script to prettyprint JSONs, long lines are gone and the default option (described above) works just fine.
- Regardless of the above, one can benefit from the inclusion mechanism when the size of the returning string content is significant. For this reason, I still consider this question to be open.

Comment: I don't understand what the direct inclusion buys you: why don't you want them as separate files?

Comment: @NickD Imagine that instead of replacing the link to `.png` image  with a `\includegraphics` command, LaTeX backend transform this link to equivalent link (link to a local file) in the output PDF, this is basically my situation.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is the long lines issue. Could it be possible to insert some newlines in the generated HTML (e.g. automatically run results through a HTML formatter)? Also, what version of Emacs are you using? A recent version (27.1 I think?) introduced better support for long lines.

Comment: You're right @ChrisClark! I modified the script to prettyprint JSONs in the output HTML strings, long lines gone, problem gone. PS. My Emacs version: 27.2.